# How does Airbnb(iOS) implement the menu effects

Tags: ios, animation

### Left menu layout

I think it's possible to use UICollectionView, but one page of menu is center-layouted and has animations and it can circle slide

### Left menu Animcation

While dragging the left menu, it has effects like text zooming out and text gap getting bigger.
It's made by UIDynamicAnimator, because Airbnb is compatible with iOS6

How will you implement it if you were developing the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/taphuochai/PHAirViewController. It is a very nice implementation of the Airbnb style menu navigation

Comment: It's difficult to customize, and different from my requirement, I implement it by myself in the end